# Firebase load image in listview using picasso

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

please, take a look, i have a fragment, set an adapter, take string url value from firebase database, but no images load.

my fragment :

```
public class PromoFragment extends Fragment {


private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

List<Promo> promoList = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listViewPromo;

public PromoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_promo, container, false);
    listViewPromo = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewPromo);
    listenPromo();  //here i load my data, i currently have 3 childs, each child has imageUrl
    PromoAdapter promoAdapter = new PromoAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_promo, promoList);
    listViewPromo.setAdapter(promoAdapter);
    return view;
}


private void listenPromo() {

    mDatabase.child("Promo").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
            // MainActivity.currUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

            for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                promoList.add(dsp.getValue(Promo.class)); //add result into array list

            }

            // ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Getting User Class data failed...
            Log.w("Canceled", "loadUserData:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            // ...

        }


    });
}
```

}

my fragment_promo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PromoFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewPromo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

list_promo.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPromo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

promo.java class

i have 3 variables for each object, but i will only use durl (url download) for this case.

```
public class Promo {
private String durl;
private Boolean active;
private String timestamp;


public Promo() {  //default constructor

}

public Promo(String durl, Boolean active, String timestamp) {
    this.durl = durl;
    this.active = active;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getDurl() {
    return durl;
}

public void setDurl(String durl) {
    this.durl = durl;
}

public Boolean getActive() {
    return active;
}

public void setActive(Boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}
```

}

PromoAdapter.java class

```
public class PromoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Promo> {

Context context;
List<Promo> myList;

public PromoAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Promo> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.myList = objects;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(myList != null)
        return myList.size();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Promo getItem(int position) {
    if(myList != null)
        return myList.get(position);
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if(myList != null)
        return myList.get(position).hashCode();
    return 0;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder;


    if (convertView == null){

        //we need a new holder to hold the structure of the cell
        holder = new Holder();

        //get the XML inflation service
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_promo, null);

        holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPromo);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();

    }     
    Promo promo = getItem(position); 
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(promo.getDurl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.coin25)
            .error(R.drawable.hnbspic)
            .into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}


private class Holder{

    ImageView imageView;

}
```

what i have tried :

1. check the image url in browser is valid
2. the listenPromo also success in getting all the children with imageurl (i've tested it before to get data from database before using picasso)
3. change `load(promo.getDurl())` to `load(uri.parse(promo.getDurl()))`
4. add placeholder and error image , also no image appear. my fragment is blank white.

please help..  if the code is working , then it should be displaying 3 images.

thank you for any attention.

Comment: May be problem is to refreshing the adapter , it sets adapter first and then get image url.just notify adapter after getting sussess ful response in onDataChange

Comment: the imageurl should be in the array before i set it to adapter.

Comment: addValueEventListener work in background so code will set it in backgroud and move to setAdapter first. can you show the full code where you set Image with Piccaso.

Comment: the whole code is all above, in the promoAdapter class

Comment: oh you're right, i put  _promoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();_  in my listener, and it works.. , please write the answer for me to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add promoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onDataChange and it will work for you.

```
mDatabase.child("Promo").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        // MainActivity.currUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

        for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            promoList.add(dsp.getValue(Promo.class)); //add result into array list

        }
         promoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting User Class data failed...
        Log.w("Canceled", "loadUserData:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...

    }




 });
```

addValueEventListener works in backgound so it will setAdater first and then you get your response.so just notify adapter will work for you.

Comment: sorry, its not listviewPromo.notifyDataSetChanged(), but promoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
   Transformation blurTransformation = new Transformation() {
            @Override
            public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
                Bitmap blurred = Blur.fastblur(context, source, 15);
                source.recycle();
                return blurred;
            }

            @Override
            public String key() {
                return "blur()";
            }
        };

     Picasso.with(context)

                    .load(R.drawable.coin25)
                    // thumbnail url goes here
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.coin25)
                    .transform(blurTransformation)
                    .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
                    .into(holder.imageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Picasso.with(context)
                                    .load(promo.getDurl()) // image url goes here
                                    .fit()
                                    .centerCrop()

                                    .error(R.drawable.hnbspic)
                                    .placeholder(holder.imageView.getDrawable())
                                    .fit()
                                    .into(holder.imageView);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }
                    });
```

try with this .if this not work for you.then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, adapter is not necessarily passing the list items. I urge you to make the **adapter globally declare** and add **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** when any changes detected on **onDataChange**.